# Cannot add metadata to BigQuery views

Tags: google-bigquery, dataform

BigQuery views cannot be assigned a primarykey or policy tag. I'd like to give both views and tables the same metadata in the same way.

Comment: Hi @naoki,I have posted a solution.If  my answer addresses your question you can consider accepting based on stack overflow guidelines else let me know so that  I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the google cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security#work_for_views) :

> Views are derived from an underlying table. The same column-level access control on the table applies when the protected columns are accessed through a view. There are two kinds of views in BigQuery, logical views and authorized views. Both types of views are derived from a source table, and both are consistent with the table's column-level access control.

So for your requirements you can consider applying the policy tag directly to  the BigQuery table.Almost similar type of  a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173805886) filed for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking the `+1` and `*STAR*` mark to receive updates on it.

For more information you can refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security#work_for_views) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security-intro#limitations).